# Spring batch tables creation fails in MariaDB

Tags: mariadb, spring-batch, entity-attribute-value

I used this schema to create Spring batch tables in MariaDB - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-core/src/main/resources/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-mysql.sql.

BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS table fails with below error

```
Error: (conn=10719030) This table type requires a primary key
SQLState:  42000
ErrorCode: 1173
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `PRIMARY KEY(JOB_EXECUTION_ID, KEY_NAME)` to `BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS` if that combination is Unique.

`BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_SEQ` also has no PK.  The `UNIQUE` key could be promoted to be the PK.  (Ditto for some other tables.)  That particular table is rather weird -- it turns a 1-byte `UNIQUE_KEY` into an 8-byte id!?!

`BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS` is a pretty awful variant of the classic EAV schema.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL and MariaDB are different products and it looks like they behave differently in regards to primary keys. You are using the MySQL DDL script against a MariaDB server which is not officially supported by Spring Batch.

So either adapt the script accordingly (by adding the primary keys manually) and be aware that Spring Batch would not necessarily work as expected since it does not support MariaDB officially, or open a feature request in the JIRA of the project to request support for MariaDB.

Comment: _... Spring Batch would not necessarily work as expected since it does
 not support MariaDB officially ..._

I know it is an old post but want to check if it is still the case as I can't find much information about supported DB engines by Spring Batch.